# how to use mongoDB database for web application without installing mongoDB on machine?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, database

I have got a task to send an application to client, that will have angular at client side with nodejs server. I need to use the database, and mongoDB is the only one which i know to use. I have built various web application with mongoDB database to store the information. surely i have installed it on windows machine. My question is, how can i use the mongoDB without installing on the machine, considering that the client will not have to go through unnecessary steps like installing mongoDB on machine and then see my demo. All i want is he runs the node server and see the demp app.
is there any mongoDB service which i can use? how to connect with node server?
please help

Answer (score 0):

You could try [modulus](https://modulus.io/), I made a simple project using their mongoDB host and it was pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the MongoDB for Windows binaries as zip file: open https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community, select the version you need, Platform: Windows and Package: zip
2. Extract it anywhere you like, for example to `C:\mongo`
3. Create the data directory (e.g. `C:\mongo\data`)
4. Run `C:\mongo\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath=C:\mongo\data`
5. To stop the MongoDB, you may just use `Control-C`